# Ninject bind generic to concrete type

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ioc-container

I want to achieve this type of binding:

```
interface IService<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
}

class StringService : IService<string>
{
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

kernel.Bind<IService<string>>().To<StringService>();
```

But it gives me an error, I've seen how to bind IService<> to ConcreteService<> already, but that's not what I want.

**Update**
It throws `Ninject.ActivationException` - *"Error activating IService No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable"*

Comment: "it gives me an error". What error? Compile-time? Runtime? Exception details (message, type and stacktrace) please.

Comment: It might be that the `StringService` class needs to be `internal` or `public` for ninject o be able to pick up it's "default constructor" (parameterless constructor). Because the binding certailny should be correct, we are using this all the time.

Comment: As the exception states, you don't have a binding for `IService` (you only got one for `IService<string>`!). So what's that `IService` interface? Is it actually `IService<T> : IService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IService<string>)).To(typeof(StringService));
```